# How to draw a vertical line between items in the list in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How to draw a vertical line connected with dots between items in the ListView?

What I am trying to do is shown [in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzTiw.png). I have a list of items and want to show users which items are already booked by connecting two dots with vertical line.

Comment: You can add another widget on List-item and handle start & end point.

Comment: check `CustomPaint` widget

Answer (score 1):

You can try `timelines: ^0.1.0` package. Add this to your package's `pubspec.yaml` file:

```
dependencies:
  timelines: ^[latest_version]
```

You can install packages from the command line:

```
flutter pub get
```

then use it based on the example [here](https://pub.dev/packages/timelines/example).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Divider widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Divider-class.html) wherever you want like this,

```
 Divider(
                color: Colors.Y, // Y is your desired color
                thickness: X, // X is your int value 
              ),
```